# Mixing px and % when layouting divs in css

Tags: html, css

I want to realize a layout with 4 divs ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3fBe.png)). **menu** should be `180px wide` and `78%` (because I have used the top 21% of the screen for other content) of screen high, while the width of the **field1_top** should be the rest of the screen and it's `height be 38%` of the screen. The **gap** between **menu** and the **others** should be `1% of screensize`.

My current best solution is:

```
div.menu{width:180px;height:78%;position:absolute;overflow:auto;left:1%;top:21%}
div.field1_top{width:84%;height:38%;position:absolute;overflow:auto;left:15%;top:21%}
div.field1_bottom_left{width:30%;height:38%;position:absolute;overflow:auto;left:15%;top:61%}
div.field1_bottom_right{width:53%;height:38%;position:absolute;overflow:auto;left:46%;top:61%}
```

Obviously this will make the gap between "menu" and the other divs variable: in small screen sizes the other boxes run into the menu and in large screens sizes the gap gets too large...

I already tried to solve this with a table around the divs or with block-level elements like in "[Issue mixing px and % for responsive layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21658968/issue-mixing-px-and-for-responsive-layout)". The **problem** I had there is that then the **other divs** took the height and width they needed for their content and **grew very large**. But I don't want the screen to be scrolled but have all the scrollbars in the divs, if they become necessary.

This is my first question and I hope I managed to explain my problem that it could be understood. Of course I would be happy if anyone could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1763906/4810983

Alternatively, you can try `calc`: https://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/
So you will have something like:

```
div.field1_top {
    width:calc(100% - 220px);
    height:38%;
    position:absolute;
    overflow:auto;
    left:200px;
    top:21%
}
```

Comment: Yes! This seems exactly what I needed. I had similiar problems before so often - but I never found this function. I can't believe I always missed that and I hope I didn't bother you with something that was clear to everyone else. In any way: thank you very much!

Comment: Just to make clearer as the answer contains 2 solutions: I tried the second answer with the calc-function. I haven't tried the first solution.